# javascript prompt multiple variables

Tags: javascript, prompt

Hopefully a straight forward one:

I would like to write some javascript code to receive multiple inputs for multiple variables from the user. A bit like a prompt but for three options (so kind of like 3 prompts on one box).

Suggestions for the best way of going about this?

Comment: That would need to be based on a custom HTML form, jqueryui option; http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: Thank you, could you give me an idea on how to code this in javascript? I'm a beginner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a form with necessary fields and place a JavaScript handler on its "submit" button.

Either create it in HTML and query elements by their ids or create directly with DOM methods from JS - you'll have direct references to elements from beginning.

Comment: Thank you, could you give me an idea on how to code this in javascript? I'm a beginner!